# Auto Update Combo box using DefaultComboBoxModel and HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I am trying to make a combo box and I made it using HashMap. It populates my combo box with name by selecting its respective id form the mysql data base. I am linking the code below.
My problem is that the combo box is not updating when I enter new data to the mysql table.
My program runs in one JFrame and different panels. I have a panel from which I enter data to mysql table and in other panel I created a combo box which populates using data from that particular mysql table.
This file is named by DB.java:

```
public class DB {
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    public static Connection dbconnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounting_software","root","dsgohel124");
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
            return null;
        } 
    }
    
    public HashMap<String, Integer> populateDropdown() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Connection con = dbconnect();
        java.sql.Statement st;
        
        try {
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT `acc_id`, `name` FROM `master_create`");
            DropdownItem di;
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                di = new DropdownItem(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
                map.put(di.getAccName(), di.getAccId());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e3) {
            System.out.println(e3);
            return null;
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

This is TransictionCreate.java:

```
    public void fromDropdown() {
        DB db = new DB();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = db.populateDropdown();
        for(String fromKey : map.keySet()) {
            from_partyValue.addItem(fromKey);
        }
    }
    
    public void toDropdown() {
        DB db = new DB();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = db.populateDropdown();
        for(String toKey : map.keySet()) {
            to_partyValue.addItem(toKey);
        }
    }
    
        JPanel TransictionCreate_panel = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(TransictionCreate_panel, "name_514503116950200");
        TransictionCreate_panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel from_party = new JLabel("From");
        from_party.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        from_party.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        from_party.setBounds(5, 170, 120, 20);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(from_party);
        
        from_partyValue = new JComboBox<String>();
        from_partyValue.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"----Select----"}));
        from_partyValue.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        from_partyValue.setBounds(150, 162, 250, 28);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(from_partyValue);
        
        JLabel to_party = new JLabel("To");
        to_party.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        to_party.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        to_party.setBounds(470, 170, 120, 20);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(to_party);
        
        to_partyValue = new JComboBox<String>();
        to_partyValue.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"----Select----"}));
        to_partyValue.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        to_partyValue.setBounds(615, 162, 250, 28);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(to_partyValue);
        
        JLabel amount = new JLabel("Amount");
        amount.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        amount.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        amount.setBounds(5, 240, 120, 20);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(amount);
        
        amountValue = new JTextField();
        amountValue.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        amountValue.setBounds(150, 234, 200, 26);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(amountValue);
        amountValue.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel date = new JLabel("Date");
        date.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        date.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        date.setBounds(470, 240, 120, 20);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(date);

        JButton createTransiction = new JButton("Create");
        createTransiction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    DB db = new DB();
                    HashMap<String, Integer> map = db.populateDropdown();
                    
                    Integer from_party=map.get(from_partyValue.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    Integer to_party=map.get(to_partyValue.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    
                    String amount=amountValue.getText();
                    
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String date=sdfDate.format(dateValue.getDate());
                    
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfDueDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String due_date=sdfDueDate.format(due_dateValue.getDate());
                    
                    String rate_of_interest=rate_of_interestValue.getText();
                    
                    String bank=(String)bankValue.getSelectedItem();
                    
                    String cheque_number=cheque_numberValue.getText();
                    String tds=tdsValue.getText();
                    
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfReceived= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String received=sdfReceived.format(receivedValue.getDate());
                    
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfDelivered= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String delivered=sdfDelivered.format(deliveredValue.getDate());
                
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `transiction_create`(`from_party`, `to_party`, `amount`, `date`, `due_date`, `rate_of_interest`, `bank`, `cheque_number`, `tds`, `received`, `delivered`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    pst.setLong(1, from_party);
                    pst.setLong(2, to_party);
                    pst.setString(3, amount);
                    pst.setString(4, date);
                    pst.setString(5, due_date);
                    pst.setString(6, rate_of_interest);
                    pst.setString(7, bank);
                    pst.setString(8, cheque_number);
                    pst.setString(9, tds);
                    pst.setString(10, received);
                    pst.setString(11, delivered);
                    
                    if(from_party.equals(to_party)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "From and To can not be same!");
                    } 
                    else {
                        pst.executeUpdate();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Added");
                        switchPanels(Print_panel);
                        
                        area.setText("                                    RECEIPT\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                        
                        Date obj = new Date();
                        String currentDate = obj.toString();
                        
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"                                     "+currentDate+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"From : "+(String)from_partyValue.getSelectedItem()+"\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"To : "+(String)to_partyValue.getSelectedItem()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Amount : "+amountValue.getText()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Date : "+sdfDate.format(dateValue.getDate())+"\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Due Date : "+sdfDueDate.format(due_dateValue.getDate())+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"ROI : "+rate_of_interestValue.getText()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Bank : "+(String)bankValue.getSelectedItem()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Cheque Number : "+cheque_numberValue.getText()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"TDS : "+tdsValue.getText()+"\n\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Received : "+sdfReceived.format(receivedValue.getDate())+"\n");
                        area.setText(area.getText()+"Delivered : "+sdfDelivered.format(deliveredValue.getDate())+"\n\n");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e4) {
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        createTransiction.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        createTransiction.setBounds(695, 516, 120, 28);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(createTransiction);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel1 = new JLabel("Transiction Create");
        lblNewLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblNewLabel1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblNewLabel1.setBounds(65, 50, 300, 25);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(lblNewLabel1);
        
        JButton btnCancel1 = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPanels(Home_panel);
            }
        });
        btnCancel1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnCancel1.setBounds(545, 516, 120, 28);
        TransictionCreate_panel.add(btnCancel1);
        
        fromDropdown();
        toDropdown();
```

Comment: *the combo box is not updating when I enter new data to the mysql table.* - there is no connection between the combo box and the database. If you update the database you also need to manually update the combo box.

Comment: @camickr My database and combo box are already connected and I am also getting the results. The problem is that if I want to see the added name in the combo box then I have to restart the program.

Comment: The contents of the combo box only get updated when `populateDropdown()` is called. Your code needs to call that method whenever new items are inserted into the database.

Comment: @MusikPolice I am calling poulateDropdown(). you can see that in fromDropdown() function (In the second part of the code).

Comment: All I see is code that updates the HashMap. I don't see where `fromDropDown` is ever called. Also, the code in `fromDropdown` is incorrect. You need to delete all the items in the combobox otherwise you will have duplicates if you just keep trying to add new items.

Comment: @camickr now I added the whole code in the question sir. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Every time you update the HashMap you need to invoke `fromDropDown()`.

Comment: @camickr can you please explain me by writing down some code.

Comment: No I can't give code because I don't know how your program works. My suggestion is simple. Your method `fromDropDown()` appears to read data from the database and add the data to the combo box, But I don't see anywhere in your code that you invoke that method. So how do you expect the combobox to be updated if you never invoke the method? So whenever you add new data to your database you need to invoke the `fromDropDown()` method.

Comment: I can't tell what your code is doing. You can step through the code to see what is happening. All I can suggest is that after you invoke `pst.executeUpdate();` which updates your database you need to update your combo box.

Comment: @camickr then it will only populate my combobox if i add new data

Comment: You need a method that populates the combo box. This method will be invoked 1) when you create all the GUI components at the beginning of your program and 2) when you update the database. So somehow you need to figure out how to invoke this method from two different places in your application.