# Add MouseListener to jComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I want add MouseListener (MouseClicked) to jCombobox in my program. But I don't know the syntax. I know that jCombobox is made up of different components so by using loop, we have to add MouseListener to each control of jCombobox. Actually, I made a function(fromDropdown()) which populates combobox with mysql data. I want to call that function(fromDropdown()) on MouseClicked event on the combobox. So that I don't have to restart my program every time after adding data to that mysql table from other Jpanel. I how you all understand my question and any solution will be much appreciated. Here are some code of my combobox.

```
private JComboBox<String> from_partyValue;

from_partyValue = new JComboBox<String>();
from_partyValue.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"----Select----"}));
from_partyValue.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
from_partyValue.setBounds(150, 162, 250, 28);
TransictionCreate_panel.add(from_partyValue);

fromDropdown();
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a MouseListener? JComboBox supports ActionListener and ItemListener and PopupListener, but ActionListener should do almost anything you need.

Comment: See: [Handling Events on a Combo Box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Comment: @NomadMaker MouseListener is not compulsory to use. I just want to update my combobox every time I click on it. So the value I get in combobox from mysql database is refreshed and new. AnyListener would help.

Comment: @camickr I don't want action by clicking Item of Jcombobox. I want action on clicking Jcombobox itself.

Comment: (1-) The combo box should be updated when you make a change to the database. I see you have already been given advice (from multiple people) in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615888/auto-update-combo-box-using-defaultcomboboxmodel-and-hashmap

Comment: @camickr I know you gave me solution there but it didn't helped me. So I tried to go other way. And I am new to programming languages so it is hard for me to understand every answer properly. Because of that I asked you to put some code but you didn't.

Comment: You were given the reason why I could not provide code. That reason has not changed. The answer is simple. Whenever you update the database you also update the combo box!!! I can't tell you what to change in your code because I don't have access to your code. It is up to you to understand the context of the suggestion and then implement the suggestion.

Comment: @camickr I have updated my question. I have uploaded full code of the program so you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Component[] comps = from_partyValue.getComponents();

for(Component c : comps) {
    if(c instanceof JButton) {
         ((JButton)c).addActionListener(e -> {
              //do something
         });
    }
}
```

and iterate through the resulting array adding a actionlistener for each component if you want separate functionality depending on which part of the jcombobox is clicked. Obviously in the code snippet above the JButton is just a place holder for what you want to monitor the clicking of.